# Unable to insert rows of a CSV file into a MYSQL database through python

Tags: python, mysql, database, pandas, mysql-connector

I need to read a CSV file that contains the number of infected people per country and per day and insert the rows into a MYSQL database using python. I have already created the database and it contains the same amount of columns as the CSV file. When I try to run the code below, I get the following error message: "ValueError: Could not process parameters". Can you please have a look and let me know if there is something wrong with he code? Many thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  passwd="xxxx",
  database="covid19_ca"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

dataframe = pd.read_csv('total_cases_modified.csv')
print(dataframe)

for row in dataframe:
    mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO covid_per_day_per_country (date, World, Afghanistan) VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s"")', row)    
    mydb.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

---

```
for _, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    values = (row['date'], row['World'], row['Afghanistan'], row['Albania'], row['Algeria'], row['Andorra'], row['Angola'], row['Anguilla'], row['AntiguaAndBarbuda'], row['Argentina'], row['Armenia'], row['Aruba'], row['Australia'], row['Austria'], row['Azerbaijan'], row['Bahamas'], row['Bahrain'], row['Bangladesh'], row['Barbados'], row['Belarus'], row['Belgium'], row['Belize'], row['Benin'], row['Bermuda'], row['Bhutan'], row['Bolivia'], row['BonaireSintEustatiusAndSaba'], row['BosniaAndHerzegovina'], row['Botswana'], row['Brazil'], row['BritishVirginIslands'], row['Brunei'], row['Bulgaria'], row['BurkinaFaso'], row['Burundi'], row['Cambodia'], row['Cameroon'], row['Canada'], row['CapeVerde'], row['CaymanIslands'], row['CentralAfricanRepublic'], row['Chad'], row['Chile'], row['China'], row['Colombia'], row['Comoros'], row['Congo'], row['CostaRica'], row['CotedIvoire'], row['Croatia'], row['Cuba'], row['Curacao'], row['Cyprus'], row['CzechRepublic'], row['DemocraticRepublicCongo'], row['Denmark'], row['Djibouti'], row['Dominica'], row['DominicanRepublic'], row['Ecuador'], row['Egypt'], row['ElSalvador'], row['EquatorialGuinea'], row['Eritrea'], row['Estonia'], row['Ethiopia'], row['FaeroeIslands'], row['FalklandIslands'], row['Fiji'], row['Finland'], row['France'], row['FrenchPolynesia'], row['Gabon'], row['Gambia'], row['Georgia'], row['Germany'], row['Ghana'], row['Gibraltar'], row['Greece'], row['Greenland'], row['Grenada'], row['Guam'], row['Guatemala'], row['Guernsey'], row['Guinea'], row['GuineaBissau'], row['Guyana'], row['Haiti'], row['Honduras'], row['Hungary'], row['Iceland'], row['India'], row['Indonesia'], row['International'], row['Iran'], row['Iraq'], row['Ireland'], row['IsleofMan'], row['Israel'], row['Italy'], row['Jamaica'], row['Japan'], row['Jersey'], row['Jordan'], row['Kazakhstan'], row['Kenya'], row['Kosovo'], row['Kuwait'], row['Kyrgyzstan'], row['Laos'], row['Latvia'], row['Lebanon'], row['Lesotho'], row['Liberia'], row['Libya'], row['Liechtenstein'], row['Lithuania'], row['Luxembourg'], row['Macedonia'], row['Madagascar'], row['Malawi'], row['Malaysia'], row['Maldives'], row['Mali'], row['Malta'], row['Mauritania'], row['Mauritius'], row['Mexico'], row['Moldova'], row['Monaco'], row['Mongolia'], row['Montenegro'], row['Montserrat'], row['Morocco'], row['Mozambique'], row['Myanmar'], row['Namibia'], row['Nepal'], row['Netherlands'], row['NewCaledonia'], row['NewZealand'], row['Nicaragua'], row['Niger'], row['Nigeria'], row['NorthernMarianaIslands'], row['Norway'], row['Oman'], row['Pakistan'], row['Palestine'], row['Panama'], row['PapuaNewGuinea'], row['Paraguay'], row['Peru'], row['Philippines'], row['Poland'], row['Portugal'], row['PuertoRico'], row['Qatar'], row['Romania'], row['Russia'], row['Rwanda'], row['SaintKittsAndNevis'], row['SaintLucia'], row['SaintVincentAndtheGrenadines'], row['SanMarino'], row['SaoTomeAndPrincipe'], row['SaudiArabia'], row['Senegal'], row['Serbia'], row['Seychelles'], row['SierraLeone'], row['Singapore'], row['SintMaarten'], row['Slovakia'], row['Slovenia'], row['Somalia'], row['SouthAfrica'], row['SouthKorea'], row['SouthSudan'], row['Spain'], row['SriLanka'], row['Sudan'], row['Suriname'], row['Swaziland'], row['Sweden'], row['Switzerland'], row['Syria'], row['Taiwan'], row['Tajikistan'], row['Tanzania'], row['Thailand'], row['Timor'], row['Togo'], row['TrinidadAndTobago'], row['Tunisia'], row['Turkey'], row['TurksAndCaicosIslands'], row['Uganda'], row['Ukraine'], row['UnitedArabEmirates'], row['UnitedKingdom'], row['UnitedStates'], row['UnitedStatesVirginIslands'], row['Uruguay'], row['Uzbekistan'], row['Vatican'], row['Venezuela', row['Vietnam'], row['WesternSahara'], row['Yemen'], row['Zambia'], row['Zimbabwe'])
    mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO covid_per_day_per_country (date, World, Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra, Angola, Anguilla, AntiguaAndBarbuda, Argentina, Armenia, Aruba, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahamas, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Barbados, Belarus, Belgium, Belize, Benin, Bermuda, Bhutan, Bolivia, BonaireSintEustatiusAndSaba, BosniaAndHerzegovina, Botswana, Brazil, BritishVirginIslands, Brunei, Bulgaria, BurkinaFaso, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, Canada, CapeVerde, CaymanIslands, CentralAfricanRepublic,Chad, Chile, China, Colombia, Comoros, Congo, CostaRica, CotedIvoire, Croatia, Cuba, Curacao, Cyprus, CzechRepublic, DemocraticRepublicCongo, Denmark, Djibouti, Dominica, DominicanRepublic, Ecuador, Egypt, ElSalvador, EquatorialGuinea, Eritrea, Estonia, Ethiopia, FaeroeIslands, FalklandIslands, Fiji, Finland, France, FrenchPolynesia,Gabon, Gambia, Georgia, Germany, Ghana, Gibraltar, Greece, Greenland, Grenada, Guam, Guatemala, Guernsey, Guinea, GuineaBissau, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Hungary, Iceland, India, Indonesia, International, Iran, Iraq, Ireland, IsleofMan, Israel, Italy, Jamaica, Japan, Jersey, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kosovo, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Laos, Latvia, Lebanon, Lesotho, Liberia, Libya, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macedonia, Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia, Maldives, Mali, Malta, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico, Moldova, Monaco, Mongolia, Montenegro, Montserrat, Morocco, Mozambique, Myanmar, Namibia, Nepal, Netherlands, NewCaledonia, NewZealand, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, NorthernMarianaIslands, Norway, Oman, Pakistan, Palestine, Panama, PapuaNewGuinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, PuertoRico, Qatar, Romania, Russia, Rwanda, SaintKittsAndNevis, SaintLucia, SaintVincentAndtheGrenadines, SanMarino, SaoTomeAndPrincipe, SaudiArabia, Senegal, Serbia, Seychelles, SierraLeone, Singapore, SintMaarten, Slovakia, Slovenia, Somalia, SouthAfrica, SouthKorea, SouthSudan, Spain, SriLanka, Sudan, Suriname, Swaziland, Sweden, Switzerland, Syria, Taiwan, Tajikistan, Tanzania, Thailand, Timor, Togo, TrinidadAndTobago, Tunisia, Turkey, TurksAndCaicosIslands, Uganda, Ukraine, UnitedArabEmirates, UnitedKingdom, UnitedStates, UnitedStatesVirginIslands, Uruguay, Uzbekistan, Vatican, Venezuela, Vietnam, WesternSahara, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe) VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")', values)
```

mydb.commit()

---

```
values = (row['Antigua and Barbuda'])
mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO covid_per_day_per_country (Antigua and Barbuda) VALUES ("%s")', values)
```

ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and Barbuda) VALUES ("%s")' at line 1

Comment: Can you include the full traceback and include your intended behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred pandas way is to use the [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) function. Install the sqlalchemy package first. Try this code then. The column names in the table and the dataframe have to be the same.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:xxxx@127.0.0.1/')
dataframe.to_sql('covid19_ca', engine)
```

If you want to keep using your code and iterate through the dataframe (note it's [not recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#iteration)), you can try something like this:

```
for _, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    values = (row['date'], row['World'], row['Afghanistan'])
    mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO covid_per_day_per_country (date, World, Afghanistan) VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', values)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Let's say I need to follow the second instruction, which is iterate, and I have 212 columns in the CSV file. Is there a faster way to make python read all the columns rather than manually specify one by one? The columns in my database are not exactly the same because I needed to adjust it and remove the reserved words when creating them. Thanks!

Comment: Are you modifying them using pandas?

Comment: If you are referring to the columns within my database, I needed to modify them manually by removing the spaces between countries with more than 2 words. This is because I was unable to create columns with the word 'And' in it. In regards to the second code you have provided, it worked well, but when I adjust it to all the 212 columns I have in the table, I get the following error message: 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'. I have provided my code on the top of the page for your reference.
 Do you know why is that? Thank you for your attention and patience.

Comment: The syntax error is coming from a missing `]` when extracting the row value for Venezuela.

Comment: thanks, that was indeed the error. The error I'm getting now is the following: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and Barbuda) VALUES ("%s")' at line 1



Do you know whether it's because I'm using reserved words in the column names? Thanks again for your help !

Comment: No, now it's an SQL error in the INSERT INTO, becuase you have a space value in the name of a (SQL table) column.

Comment: are spaces not allowed? Initially I had removed the spaces from the column names, but then I decided to drop the table and recreate it with spaces so it reflects how the the CSV file is written. As MYSQL suggests, I've used back quotes when creating the columns